# Linear map is given by a matrix with respect to two bases, how should you find the matrix of the same map with respect to different bases?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

As an example:

Let $U=ℂ^2$ and $V=ℂ$, viewed as vector spaces over $ℂ$. Let $f:U→V$ be the linear map represented by the matrix
$$ (1+3i, 4+2i) $$
with respect to the standard bases of $ℂ^2$ and $ℂ$.

Determine the matrix of the same map with respect to the bases B = {$(1,0),(i,0),(0,1),(0,i)$}   and   C = {$1,i$} .

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The matrix of a transformation $T:U \to V$ with respect to bases $\mathcal B = \{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ and $\mathcal C = \{w_1,\dots,w_m\}$ has the form
$$
[T]_{\mathcal B \to \mathcal C} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
[T(v_1)]_{\mathcal C} & [T(v_2)]_{\mathcal C} & \cdots & [T(v_n)]_{\mathcal C}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $[w]_{\mathcal C}$ is the coordinate vector of $w$ relative to the basis $\mathcal C$.